# Mongoid Revert if fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, error-handling, mongoid

I have a validations in mongoid that I want to revert if it fails while saving the error message.

Example

```
if @thing.update_attributes(params[:thing])
  format.html { redirect_to @thing, notice: 'Thing was successfully updated.' }
  format.json { head :no_content }
else
  #revert the fields that have changed and keep @thing.errors
  format.html { render action: "edit" }
  format.json { render json: @thing.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }   
end
```

when I save off the document and reinsert it, it seems to not want to assign `@thing.errors = errors`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Active Model Dirty module, see here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html